# Crawling a certain depth per site in Nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, depth

I'm trying to crawl a large number of sites using Nutch V1.12, while I have no problem crawling sites I can't controll the crawl as much as I would like. The problem mainly lies with that there doesn't seem to be possible to do a crawl where the depth is counted from each new host it reaches. As I understand it a round in the crawl-script is considered as depth of the crawl. But this means that sites that are found early in the crawl is crawled more than those sites found later.

Is there a way to achieve this functionallity of a crawl depth per site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem mainly lies with that there doesn't seem to be possible to do a crawl where the depth is counted from each new host it reaches.

Correct, the depth is counted from the seeds, regardless of where the URLs are in a particular site.

> As I understand it a round in the crawl-script is considered as depth of the crawl.

No. The depth is generated by the scoring-depth plugin, regardless of the number of rounds. They are often the same, especially at the beginning of a crawl, but not necessarily.

> But this means that sites that are found early in the crawl is crawled more than those sites found later.

Yes. The depth limitation is useful for cases where we want to the crawl to stay within the boundaries of the seeds. For crawls that go beyond the original domains, you'll get the limitations you highlighted.

It should be possible to modify the code so that the depth is reset when changing host or domain but this will cause all sorts of issues e.g. what if the target URL does not correspond to the root? e.g. you'd get domain.com/path with depth 0 but if the latter has a link to domain.com/, it would get a depth of 1, which is not intuitive.

I suppose the term depth is slightly ambiguous or misleading in Nutch. 'step' would be a more accurate one as it does not assume any place within a site's hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the scoring-depth plugin to reset on each new host. To know which hosts are new I make a list where I enter all hosts. So if the host is not in the list I update the list by adding the new host and then resetting the depth to 0.